# Android and iOS push app start?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have build a Phonegap (jquery) app. Now I would like to start this app when some event happens at server side. I have read that Apple offer APNs, that can start the App when you send a new notification. Is there something similar for Android? My problem simplified: I have an Android and an iPhone app (written in Phonegap). This two apps are talking to a server, at one point they send a date to the server and I would like for the App to be started at this date.

Comment: There is something similar sir! It's called Google Cloud Messaging. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: That is what I was looking for...thnx... just one more thing, is there any web service to which you could register your phone with javascript? And webservice would then send push notification to registered devices?

Comment: I don't quite follow... What do you mean by register your phone with javascript?

Comment: Let me simplify.. App is build entirely in javascript and it runs in webview on android (phonegap app). I want to send a date to my server, I do this with ajax everything ok...but now I want this app to be opened at mobile when this date is reached. I want to send some kind of notification to android via my server. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar sir! It's called [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)